# Help understanding Count Zero's ending

Tags: count-zero

I've recently finished William Gibson's *Count Zero*, and I admit I have no idea of what the ending lines mean.

I'm not a native English speaker, but I went through the whole book with no major issues, apart from searching a few words here and there, so I'm not sure I could blame the language.

The ending lines for the book are as follows:

> "Is that true?" he asked his father when his was father through explaining about the squirrels. "They're just so dumb they'll come back over and over and get shot?"
>
> "Yes", Turner said, "it is". Then he smiled. "Well, almost always...."

I guess that it could be a reference to Sally, making several mistakes during her life and being saved by Rudy after one of them, but I'm not completely sure and I hate to fail at understanding such an important line as the last one, even if it's just probably a "funny" reference.

If anyone wonders why I'm not reading it in my native language (Spanish), the reason is because most (not all of them) of these kind of "tech-novels" are poorly translated into Spanish, and it's even harder to understand certain aspects of the plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I interpreted that as being about Turner himself. He got out of the violent life and career he had and settled down to raise a child. He’s a person who used to always go back, again and again, but finally broke the cycle and didn’t go back.

I don’t think it’s meant to be funny. Also, it might be expecting too much to think that it’s a concise summary of a major plot line. It might just be what felt like a good note to end on by Gibson.

Answer (score 7):

According to [***William Gibson: A Literary Companion***](https://mcfarlandbooks.com/product/william-gibson/) by **Tom Henthorne**:

> Gibson also focuses more on characterization in Count Zero than he does in Neuromancer, filling in characters' back stories and developing more complex relationships between them. **His development of Turner is perhaps most telling since at first Turner seems to be the type of simply-drawn character one might find in a 1930s detective novel.** Literally blown apart and then reassembled at the beginning of the novel at Conroy's behest so he can lead the Mitchell defection mission, he is mentally unstable, having only a professional know-how to draw upon.
>
> Unlike Armitage in Neuromancer, who unravels as the novel proceeds, **Turner gradually recovers himself, largely because he returns to his childhood home, reconnecting with his brother, and because he establishes a bond with Angelina**, becoming increasingly paternal towards her. **That he has ultimately been rehumanized becomes evident at the end of the novel** when he leaves his profession, returning to the ranch he grew tip on to start a family. The novel closes with Turner reflecting that he is no longer like the 'dumb" squirrels who return to the same place 'over and over and get shot".